# Pivotal Cloud Foundry - Log4j MDC( or Log4j2 ThreadContext) automatically getting cleared in WebListener destroyed method

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2, cloud-foundry

I have these use case where i have to extract some fields from http request header and set it to log4j thread local MDC object. To achieve this i have implemented following

```
import javax.servlet.ServletRequestListener;

@WebListener
public class HttpRequestEventListener implements ServletRequestListener {

  private static final Logger log = org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
      .getLogger(HttpRequestEventListener.class);

  @Override
  public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent sre) {
     if (sre.getServletRequest() instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
           HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) sre.getServletRequest();
           MDC.put("ip", request.getRemoteAddr());
           MDC.put("app-name", "my-awesome-app);
     }
  }

  @Override
  public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent sre) {
      log.info("Final response");
  }
}
```

As you can see I have set some values in thread local MDC object inside requestInitialized() method which I expected should still be available in any log statement inside requestDestroyed().
I put some sysout() to verify if the thread which is handling requestInitialized() method is same as requestDestroyed() and observe it's the same thread. Do note that MDC values set in Listener are available in Filter,Servlet, Spring Interceptor, Controller etc. **Its not only available in Listener's requestDestroyed() method.**

Do note that I tried to do the same using a servlet Filter and noticed that it's working as intended. However my application use some legacy code which has many filters and can not control the order of filter registration. MDC values need to be available in any log statement for a web request. So I thought of having it done via WebListener which gets executed before Filter.

**My Application:** Spring boot 2 app with Tomcat as web container

Note that when I tested the listener my local, i see all the MDC values available. But when i deployed it to Pivotal Cloud Foundry(Platform as a Service), I dont see it.

Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you add more details about how you run locally? What OS, version of Java, version of Tomcat? Is Tomcat stand-alone or embedded w/Spring Boot? What specific version of spring boot? Also, full output of `cf push` would be helpful, as well as the output of `cf logs` while you're pushing your app.

Comment: In my local I am running it on a MacOS(Mojave), with spring boot(2.0.1.RELEASE) embedded tomcat.

For `cf push` and `cf logs` output i cant seems to copy-paste it here as it limits to 500 chars only.

Comment: I managed to upload it in S3

**cf-logs**
https://stackoverflowhelp.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/cf-logs.txt

**cf-push**
https://stackoverflowhelp.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/cf-push.txt

Note that, due to security reason I had to strip off/change some of the logs. But crux of it should be present

Comment: Well, you have the same Spring Boot version and thus the same Tomcat version so that's a start. Check your JVM version, make sure that's the same in both places. You have OpenJDK 1.8.0_232 locally, maybe try running OpenJDK in a docker container to compare. That'll also rule out your OS differences. Aside from that, I see you have specified a fixed command to start your app. That's discouraged for Java apps. You should let the JBP pick your start command. Try pushing with `cf push -c null` to reset that to use the default and of course remove it from your manifest.yml, if it's in there.

Comment: You might also want to try the `cf local` plugin. This will let you run the buildpacks and stage your app in a local docker container. That should give you an environment that's very similar to CF, but outside of CF (it's all run local on your machine in Docker).  https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cflocal

Comment: My local has Oracle JDK `java version "1.8.0_211"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)` Also when running locally using `cf local` I cant get the app started due to SSL handshake error. My app when deployed to PCF uses a custom CA. Looking at the cf local release notes it says **No support for adding custom CAs to the system CA store**